How to report `redefined-argument-from-local` as error in ruff?
In order to avoid making another bug due to override the function arguments in a for-loop, I find that there is a lint rule redefined-argument-from-local can detect this error. I try to enable this rule by add it to pyproject.toml and add --preview args in VsCode setting. But it is just warning not error.
#pyproject.toml

[tool.ruff]
line-length = 120

[tool.ruff.lint]
extend-select = ["PLR1704"]

# vscode workspace setting
{
    "ruff.lint.args": [
        "--preview"
    ]
}

Does I do it wrong with the setting?
Besides, is there any other method to detect this notorious problem in Python?


"But it is just warning not error."

So it raises but not at the level you would want ?

@Pierre.Sassoulas Yes, I would like to increase the report level to error.

Not possible in pylint (https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/2293), though I don't know about ruff. I would suggest disabling error/warning you don't care about and care about error AND warning that are enabled.
